# Running WebGL shaders on travis-ci

Tags: configuration, webgl, travis-ci

I have a [project](https://github.com/Strilanc/Quantum-Circuit-Inspector) that uses travis-ci to auto-test anything I push to github.

A core part of the project is doing computation on the GPU via webgl. However, when I run tests on travis-ci, all the webgl bits will fail. In particular, the following function will evaluate to false:

```
function checkWebGL() {
  if (WebGLRenderingContext === undefined) return false;
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('webgl') ||
                canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
  return context instanceof WebGLRenderingContext;
}
```

Basically that function returning false means webgl support isn't present. Without webgl support, I can't run many of the project's tests. Which makes it easy to accidentally break the build. So that's why I'm here asking about it.

**Is no-web-gl an intended limitation of travis-ci, or is it just a configuration error on my part?**

Here's [the project's `.travis.yml` file](https://github.com/Strilanc/Quantum-Circuit-Inspector/blob/master/.travis.yml):

```
sudo: false
language: node_js
node_js: 5.1
install: npm install
before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
script: npm run test-firefox
addons:
  firefox: "latest"
```

(The actual testing is done [with Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/plus/Travis-CI.html). I won't go into the gory details of how the javascript is built and bootstrapped since it's not relevant.)

Comment: ISTR Travis supporting OGL, not sure about WGL, though.

Answer (score 1):

the gl part should using [headless-gl](https://github.com/stackgl/headless-gl) which is working great in all different environments

Comment: That does look promising... but when I run `npm install gl` I just get an error which amounts to "I don't work on windows unless you have X/Y/Z installed". I'm not going to burden me-five-years-from-now with that kind of 'I-snuck-a-manual-dependency-into-your-automatic-dependency-manager' nonsense.